# Angular JS with Twitter Bootstrap JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am expecting architectural perspectives from the people to decide whether we can go with **Angular + Bootstrap model** or not.

can you please share your experience with me?

**1. Pros using angularjs + bootstrap:**

**2. Cons using angularjs + bootstrap:**

**3. Other comments/remarks/findings:**

Comment: What are you talking about ? CSS framework "Twitter bootstrap" (this or another won't make a difference) or angular port of twitter bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) ?

Comment: CSS framework "Twitter bootstrap"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the principle of separation of concerns, styling your app (CSS) is independant of its structure.

You can use whatever CSS framework you want : Foundation, Twitter Bootstrap, Knacks, blueprint, etc... or no framework at all

and you can use it with angular, backbone, emberjs or whatever JS framework you want.

But some frameworks have angular modules to help you create interface. It's the case of :

- Twitter Bootstrap and its angular module : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
- Foundation and its angular module : http://madmimi.github.io/angular-foundation/
- ionic framework which is optimized for angularjs : http://ionicframework.com/

Hope this helps